# Unity - Reversing Lerped Position Back to Original Position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, lerp

My logic must be quite off here. Essentially, I have a loading bar, that when activated by a mouse hover, will have it's overlaying UI panel left position increase to give the loading effect. This works fine.

The problem is with reversing the UI panel left position back to its original posion (0,0) when its not activated in the second while loop. Here is my code -

```
IEnumerator LerpCoroutine()
{
    Vector2 xyz;

    float timeElapsed = 0;
    float lerpDuration = 2;

    Vector2 startPos = sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin;
    Vector2 x = new Vector2(0, 0);


    while (isActivated && timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
    {
        xyz = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, new Vector2(300, 0), EaseOut(timeElapsed / lerpDuration));
        sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin = xyz;
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    while (!isActivated && timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
    {
        xyz = Vector2.Lerp(sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin, new Vector2(0, 0), EaseOut(timeElapsed / lerpDuration));
        sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin = xyz;
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

For some reason, sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin is set to zero in the second while loop, thus the UI panel left position shoots right back to (0,0).

If anyone could show a better way to do this, maybe without even having to use the double while statement, that would be hugely appreciated!

**TLDR - I want to get the Vector2 to lerp from (0,0) -> (0,300) if isActivated. However, if !isActivated in the middle of the lerp transition, in which case it only went from (0,0) -> (0,150), then I want it to go from (0,150) -> (0,0).**

Thanks.

Comment: Do you simply want to get 0 to 1 in one condition and 1 to 0 in another?

Comment: Close. I want to get (0,0) -> (0,300) if hovered. However, if unhovered in the middle of the lerp transition in which case it only went from (0,0) -> (0,150), then I want it to go from (0,150) -> (0,0) during that unhover. Sorry that wasn't more clear in the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I see:

In the second loop, you're lerping from `sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin` back to `(0,0)`, but you're immediately updating `sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin` right after that. So, on the next iteration, you're lerping from the updated `sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin`, but by a larger amount since the lerp factor is based on the time delta.

Also, you're starting the second lerp at `timeElapsed / lerpDuration`. I imagine that you want the lerp factor to start at `0`, not at some larger value.

So, I'd try this.

Also, I haven't tried to compile this.

```
IEnumerator LerpCoroutine()
{
    Vector2 xyz;

    float timeElapsed = 0;
    float lerpDuration = 2;
    float lerpFactor = 0; 

    Vector2 startPos = sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin;
    Vector2 x = new Vector2(0, 0);
    var lerpMax = new Vector3(300,0);


    while (isActivated && timeElapsed < lerpDuration)
    {
        xyz = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, lerpMax, EaseOut(lerpFactor / lerpDuration));
        sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin = xyz;
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        /// increasing lerpFactor so the bar moves right...
        lerpFactor += time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    while (!isActivated && lerpFactor >= 0)
    {
        xyz = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, lerpMax, EaseOut(lerpFactor / lerpDuration));
        sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin = xyz;
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
        /// decreasing lerpFactor here so the bar moves left
        lerpFactor -= Time.deltatime; 
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

**TL;DR**

Keep your starting position on the second loop constant, make sure the lerp value makes sense, and you should be good.

Comment: That plugged right in and worked great. I never thought to use the lerpFactor variable you used. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the Coroutine function (thanks to Dave) after some cleanup -

```
IEnumerator FadeInMaterial()
{
    Vector2 lerpedOffsetMin;
    Vector2 startPos = new Vector3(0, 0);
    Vector2 endPos = new Vector3(300, 0);

    float lerpDuration = 2;
    float reverseLerpDurationMultiple = 2; // 2 would make it twice as fast when reversing
    float lerpFactor = 0;

    while (isActivated && lerpFactor < lerpDuration)
    {
        lerpedOffsetMin = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, endPos, EaseOut(lerpFactor / lerpDuration));
        sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin = lerpedOffsetMin;
        /// increasing lerpFactor so the bar moves right...
        lerpFactor += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    while (!isActivated && lerpFactor >= 0)
    {
        lerpedOffsetMin = Vector2.Lerp(startPos, endPos, EaseOut(lerpFactor / lerpDuration));
        sliderOverlayRt.offsetMin = lerpedOffsetMin;
        /// decreasing lerpFactor here so the bar moves left
        lerpFactor -= Time.deltaTime * reverseLerpDurationMultiple;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```